# Use navigation properties more than once C# EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have this Database structure

```
public class Gameboard
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Round { get; set; }
    public int MaxTries { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ColorGameBoard> Colors { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ColorGameBoard> CorrectColors { get; set; }

}
public class Color
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ColorGameBoard> ColorGameBoards { get; set; }

}
public class ColorGameBoard
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GameBoardId { get; set;}
    public Gameboard Gameboard { get; set; }
    public int CorrectColorId { get; set; }
    public Color CorrectColors { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

}
```

This is how I create the relations:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<ColorGameBoard>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Gameboard)
            .WithMany(x => x.CorrectColors)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CorrectColorId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ColorGameBoard>()
          .HasOne(x => x.Gameboard)
          .WithMany(x => x.Colors)
          .HasForeignKey(x => x.ColorId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ColorGameBoard>()
           .HasOne(x => x.Color)
           .WithMany(x => x.ColorGameBoards)
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.GameBoardId);
```

I get this error:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'Gameboard.Colors' and 'ColorGameBoard.Gameboard' because a relationship already exists between 'Gameboard.CorrectColors' and 'ColorGameBoard.Gameboard'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'ColorGameBoard.Gameboard' first in 'OnModelCreating'.
>
> Database structure: On Gameboard has two list with colors. Each list should contain at least 5 colors. And every color in the database can be used on several gameboard. Furthermore, a color can be used as many times a wanted on a gameboard.

Anyone know how to fix that error?

Comment: You need two junction classes, `ColorGameBoard` and `CorrectColorGameBoard`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some contrast relationship problems in your code. There are two `ICollection<ColorGameBoard>`  in the Gameboard class, but only one  `Gameboard` is included in the ColorGameBoard class. In this way, an error will occur when constructing the database. The number of comparison relationships should be consistent. When you build InverseProperty Attribute in EF Core , you can use some attributes like :`virtual`,`ForeignKey`,`InverseProperty`.

I don't know what your needs for the database are,SO I write two demos,Here is my code:

**The first demo,Two `class Gameboard` corresponds to one `class Color`.**

Gameboard.class

```
public class Gameboard
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Round { get; set; }
        public int MaxTries { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("GameboardOne")]
        public ICollection<ColorGameBoard> OneBorad { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("GameboardTwo")]
        public ICollection<ColorGameBoard> TwoBoard { get; set; }

    }
```

Color.class

```
public class Color
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Color")]
        public ICollection<ColorGameBoard> ColorGameBoards { get; set; }
    }
```

ColorGameBoard.class

```
public class ColorGameBoard
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GameboardOne")]
        public int OneId { get; set; }
        public virtual Gameboard GameboardOne { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GameboardTwo")]
        public int TwoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Gameboard GameboardTwo { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Color")]
        public int ColorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Color Color { get; set; }
    }
```

modelBuilder

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<ColorGameBoard>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Color)
                .WithMany(a =>a.ColorGameBoards)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.ColorId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ColorGameBoard>()
                .HasOne(d => d.GameboardOne)
                .WithMany(e => e.OneBorad)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.OneId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction); 

            modelBuilder.Entity<ColorGameBoard>()
                .HasOne(d => d.GameboardTwo)
                .WithMany(e => e.TwoBoard)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.TwoId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Then,You can create the database

[image]

**The second demo,One `class Gameboard` corresponds to two `class Color`.**

Gameboard.class

```
public class Gameboard
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Round { get; set; }
        public int MaxTries { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Gameboard")]
        public ICollection<ColorGameBoard> Colors { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Color.class

```
public class Color
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Color")]
        public ICollection<ColorGameBoard> ColorGameBoards { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("CorrectColors")]
        public ICollection<ColorGameBoard> CorrectColors { get; set; }
    }
```

ColorGameBoard.class

```
public class ColorGameBoard
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Gameboard")]
        public int GameBoardId { get; set; }
        public virtual Gameboard Gameboard { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CorrectColors")]
        public int CorrectColorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Color CorrectColors { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Color")]
        public int ColorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Color Color { get; set; }
    }
```

modelBuilder

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<ColorGameBoard>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Gameboard)
                .WithMany(x => x.Colors)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.GameBoardId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ColorGameBoard>()
              .HasOne(x => x.CorrectColors)
              .WithMany(x => x.CorrectColors)
              .HasForeignKey(x => x.CorrectColorId)
              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ColorGameBoard>()
               .HasOne(x => x.Color)
               .WithMany(x => x.ColorGameBoards)
               .HasForeignKey(x => x.ColorId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Then, You can create the databse

[image]

Comment: What do I do when I want to add a list of colors to the gameboard? I have this code now:    var gameboard = new Gameboard()
            {
                Id = GenerateRandomId(),
                Colors = db.GameboardColors.Where(x => x.GameBoardId == id).ToList(),
                MaxTries = numberOfGuesses,
                Round = 1,
            };

Comment: @raj I highly doubt the correctness of both designs. As I said above, I think you simply need two junction classes, so you can handle the lists of colors independently.